# complex Mobile Safari multitouch detection

Tags: javascript, ios, html, cordova, multi-touch

Would it be possible to do something like this:
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/foot-fairy-fun-kids-shoe-measurement/id460810086?mt=8

This is rather complex multitouch detection I'd like to implement through my PhoneGap app...

Thank you,
regards

Answer (score 0):

Why not. The touch event will give you every touch contact with your screen:

```
$(document).on("touch.YourEventIdentifier", touchFunction);
function touchFunction(event){
    if(event.originalEvent.targetTouches && event.originalEvent.targetTouches.length > 0){
        console.log(event.originalEvent.targetTouches); // Touches
        console.log(event.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].clientX); // X coordinate for the first touch
    }
}
```